# how to install photoshop in ubuntu 16.04 and where do I type commands?

Tags: apt, sudo

I am trying to install photoshop on ubuntu 16.04. I read the solution, but where do I type commands like `sudo apt-get install wine` ?

Comment: You type them in the `Terminal` application.

Comment: CTRL-ALT-T key combo will open one for you.

Comment: Personally I would use Gimp natively instead....

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will open a black window that looks like it comes straight from a hacker movie or an episode of CSI or something.

There will probably be something there waiting for you like this:

```
username@mycomputer:~$
```

This is called the shell, and you may type your commands there.

Hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button to run any commands that you type into this prompt. When the command you're running is done, the same prompt will come right back up again, ready for a new command.

Note that you need to be careful with the Terminal because it's CaSe sensitive. If you type a command in the wrong case, your command won't work, or do weird things to your system.

It is important to know that the Terminal is an ***advanced feature*** of Ubuntu, and can potentially be very dangerous if you muck around in it without any understanding of how it works.

As such, be sure to resist the urge to randomly type quickly and say things like "I'm building a program in Visual Basic to triangulate the killer's IP address and cross-reference it against the CPU database that we have on the killer's IMEI." Doing this may *actually* break your system by accident.

Answer (score 4):

**Where to type the commands:**

Type them in the computer terminal.

You can easily get to a terminal in Ubuntu by clicking the launch button and typing `terminal`.  (*The launch button can be your friend and find many things you might look for.*)

Alternatively you can use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

**How to Install Photoshop in Ubuntu**

While the steps you mentioned in your orignal message will can get `Photo Shop` installed, a simpler method might be to use `Playonlinux` which has many defaults settings for the install preconfigured.

You can install Photoshop via `playonlinux` by:

Using `playonlinux` to install Windows Programs:

Run this line in the terminal (the `$` represent the command prompt you'll see at in the terminal):

```
$ sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then Run `playonlinux` from the launch bar.

Click the Install Button -> Graphics -> and answer the prompts.

**Ubuntu's native Alternative to Photoshop**

You might consider looking at the Linux native alternative which is `gimp`.  You can install this by running from the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Type the command in in my answer in a terminal window.  Then as the answer says, launch `playonlinux`  from the `launch` button.  This will give a graphic interface just following the prompts.  Everything else is seamless and automatic.  You can do this for many Windows programs.  It works very well for Photoshop.

Comment: The question was how to get the terminal window.

Comment: @Pilot6 Steps for getting to the terminal is in my answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'll change the order and put the terminal access method up top.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the `terminal` and run those commands

> ```
> ctrl + alt + t
> ```

short cut to open the terminal
and run the following commands to install `wine`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks
```

Then install your `PSD` application after running the `wine`

The equivalent software for the PSD is `GIMP` try that once

Comment: The question was "where to type these commands". But you gave some commands to type )))